# How to create a team on a single GCP billing account, without providing a domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, organization, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to set up a GCP account, and add several people to this account to do work.

My understanding is that this should be done via an "Organization" I create via the GCP, which will give me admin privileges and the ability to add others:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

I am then directed to create either a "Google Workplace" or "Cloud Identity" which requires a web domain. But I don't want to give a web domain---I simply want to create a team of developers to use the same billing account on GCP.

How does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have a domain and do not have either Google Worspace or Cloud Identity, then you cannot create an Organization.

> An Organization resource is available for Google Workspace and Cloud
> Identity customers.

[Quickstart using organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations)

[Creating and managing organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization)

> I simply want to create a team of developers to use the same billing
> account on GCP.

Billing: You have a payment account attached to a billing account. Multiple projects can be attached to a billing account. Even without an Organization, you can have multiple projects paid by the same (or different) billing account.

Users: You can add any number of users to a project. These users (IAM members) are required to have a Google Accounts identity. This typically means user@gmail.com. You cannot use email addresses from you own systems. They must be from Google Accounts, Google Identity or Google Workspace.

Note: I am ignoring federation and features that are not in production. There are new services coming online in 2021.

Comment: Thank you. I think this clarifies things---I just wanted to make sure I understood this process correctly

Comment: I guess I am interested---for the organization, couldn't I create something analogous to a gmail account? What I currently don't understand is, I have no domain to give. How can I make one quickly with Google? (I apologize if this is obvious but...I'm a bit lost)

Comment: @EB2127 Purchasing a domain name is (usually) cheap these days. There are even registrars that offer free domains. Google offers Google Domains (i use this service) https://domains.google/ and Freenom offers free and paid (I also use this service) https://www.freenom.com/en/freeandpaiddomains.html If you go with Google Domains, the setup is almost effortless with getting the domain working and setup with Google Cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley GCP rejected my workspace registration - it didn't tell me why - but I wonder if it's because Google blocks anything from freenom (based on reputational value)

Comment: @strongline - Did you purchase a domain from Freenon? If not the registration is only valid for 90 days which disqualifies the domain.